# Assistance Refactoring Pyspark Replace Code for Synapse Notebook (working with JSON)

Tags: python, json, replace, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

Could anyone help with advice on how to refactor this code to make it faster? We are ingesting JSON and transforming in preparation for a later step but this particular section of the Notebook is taking a lot longer than expected (and we're new to python). Code is below, thanks!

```
    import pandas as pd

    df_main = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
    df_parameters = pd.DataFrame(parameter_data)

    # Convert df_parameters to dictionary for faster lookups
    parameter_dict = dict(zip(df_parameters['abc'], df_parameters['def']))

    def replace_parameters(row):
        if isinstance(row['expression'], str) and row['xyz'] == row['xyz']:
            for parameter_name, value in parameter_dict.items():
                if row['expression']:
                    row['expression'] = row['expression'].replace(f'|{parameter_name}|', str(value))
                if row['sp']:
                    row['sp'] = row['sp'].replace(f'|{parameter_name}|', str(value))
        return row

    # Apply the replacement function only when xyz is equal to xyz
    df_main = df_main.apply(replace_parameters, axis=1)
```

Comment: provide sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `for loop`, use pattern matching. I believe this kind of expression you are using; if not, adjust the pattern accordingly.

**Expressions I used:**

1. `|param1| + |param2|`
2. `|param2| - |param3|`
3. `|param1| * |param3|`
4. `|param2| / |param3|`

You can use the code below.

Data I used:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

table_data = {
    'expression': ['|param1| + |param2|', '|param2| - |param3|'],
    'sp': ['|param1| * |param3|', '|param2| / |param3|'],
    'xyz': [1, 2]  # Sample values for 'xyz'
}

parameter_data = {
    'abc': ['param1', 'param2', 'param3'],
    'def': [10, 20, 30]  # Sample values for parameters
}

df_main = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
df_parameters = pd.DataFrame(parameter_data)
```

Output:

[image]

Modify your function like below:

```py
import re
parameter_dict = dict(zip(parameter_data['abc'], parameter_data['def']))

tmp = [ "\|" +i+ "\|" for i in parameter_data['abc']]
param_pattern = '|'.join(tmp)

# Define a function to perform replacements
def replace_parameters(row):
    if isinstance(row['expression'], str) and row['xyz'] == row['xyz']:
        row['expression'] = re.sub(param_pattern,lambda match: str(parameter_dict[match.group(0).strip('|')]), row['expression'])
        row['sp'] = re.sub(param_pattern, lambda match: str(parameter_dict[match.group(0).strip('|')]), row['sp'])
    return row

df_main = df_main.apply(replace_parameters, axis=1)

df_main
```

Output:

[image]

You can see the parameters are replaced. Once again, I am saying, according to your expressions, you create the pattern. For the above kind of expressions, below is the pattern I created: `'\\|param1\\||\\|param2\\||\\|param3\\|'`.

Comment: Thanks so much JayashankarGS! We used a variation of this and also moved the order of our calls and what is included in the loop - with good results.